# How to extract items inside a table using scrapy

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract all the functions listed inside the table in the below link : [python functions list](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html)

I have tried using the chrome developers console to get the exact xpath to be used in the file `spider.py` as below:

```
$x('//*[@id="built-in-functions"]/table[1]/tbody//a/@href')
```

but this returns a list of all href's ( which I think what the xpath expression refers to).
[image]

I need to extract the text from here I believe but appending `/text()` to the above xpath return nothing. Can someone please help me to extract the function names from the table.

Comment: `$x('//*[@id="built-in-functions"]//a').forEach(elt => { console.log(elt.href);} ) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick

```
response.css('.docutils .reference .pre::text').extract()
```

a non-exact xpath equivalent of it (but that also works in this case) would be:

```
response.xpath('//table[contains(@class, "docutils")]//*[contains(@class, "reference")]//*[contains(@class, "pre")]/text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for td in response.css("#built-in-functions > table:nth-child(4) td"):
    td.css("span.pre::text").extract_first()
```